# Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration

Tags: autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

How do I open the `Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration` panel from the beginning when I start the viewer?

I want to start the live review from the beginning without clicking.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Once the extension is loaded in the viewer, you can activate it programmatically like so:

```js
const collaborationExt = viewer.getExtension('Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration');
collaborationExt.activate();
```

Comment: const collaborationExtPromise = viewer.loadExtension("Autodesk.Viewing.Collaboration");
 collaborationExtPromise.then(function (extension) {
  extension.activate();
 });

Comment: Yep, if your extension isn't loaded yet (i.e., if you didn't load it via the `GuiViewer3D` constructor) you'd have to call `loadExtension` and wait for the promise to be resolved. But if the extension is loaded already, you can just call the synchronous `getExtension`. Cheers!

Comment: I understand.　Cheers!